# Typescript: correctly infer arguments and return type for wrapped function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a wrapper function that takes in a query and a reducer, then returns essentially the same function, but with an additional property (`_data`) that contains a processed version of the query data (specifically, I want to cast the query result to an [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) record).

I'd like this function to be generic over any possible query, and preserve the call signature and type information from the query. I've attempted to do this by using `Parameters<typeof queryHook>` and `ReturnType<typeof queryHook>`. However, when I pass the arguments to `queryHook` in the inner function, Typescript complains that the arguments aren't assignable to the inner function, even though they should be typed *from* that function's parameters.

My question is, **why can't Typescript tell that the arguments being passed to the wrapped query should be of identical type to the the query's expected arguments?**

Currently, it gives an error that suggests that the `queryHook` could be any of the possible queries, not the specific one that was passed to the function.

Weirdly, if I actually use the function, all types are inferred correctly...

My code is as follows:

```js
/** List of all possible hooks to wrap */
type AllQueryHooks = typeof useGetPaymentsQuery | typeof useGetAddressesQuery

/**
 * @param queryHook GraphQL query to wrap
 * @param reducer Function to transform GraphQL result. Return value will be
 *     available on the _data prop
 */
export function wrapGQLHook<T, Hook extends AllQueryHooks>(
  queryHook: Hook,
  reducer: (data: ReturnType<typeof queryHook>['data']) => T,
): (
  ...args: Parameters<typeof queryHook>
) => ReturnType<typeof queryHook> & { _data: T | undefined } {
  function wrappedGQLHook(...args: Parameters<typeof queryHook>) {
    const queryResult = queryHook(...args)
    // ...args is overloaded      ^^^^^^^
    let _data: T | undefined = undefined
    if (queryResult.data) {
      _data = reducer(queryResult.data)
    }
    return { ...queryResult, _data }
  }
  return wrappedGQLHook
  //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not assignable to ReturnType<Hook>
}
/**
 * Wrapped useGetPaymentsQuery hook
 *
 * Returns useGetPaymentsQuery vars, plus a _data prop containing a List of
 * PaymentRecords
 */
export const useGetPaymentsQueryWrapped = wrapGQLHook(
  useGetPaymentsQuery,
  (data) => {
    if (!data) return
    const { Payments } = data
    return Payments.edges.map((node) => node)
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^   return type inferred correctly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  },
)
```

The first error (`const queryResult = queryHook(...args)`) is as follows:

```
Argument of type 'QueryHookOptions<GetPaymentsQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>> | QueryHookOptions<GetAddressesQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(QueryHookOptions<GetPaymentsQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>> & QueryHookOptions<GetAddressesQuery, Exact<{ ...; }>>) | undefined'.
  Type 'QueryHookOptions<GetPaymentsQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>>' is not assignable to type 'QueryHookOptions<GetPaymentsQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>> & QueryHookOptions<GetAddressesQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>>'.
    Type 'QueryHookOptions<GetPaymentsQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>>' is not assignable to type 'QueryHookOptions<GetAddressesQuery, Exact<{ personId: string | number; }>>'.
      Type 'GetAddressesQuery' is not assignable to type 'GetPaymentsQuery'.
        Property 'Payments' is missing in type 'GetAddressesQuery' but required in type '{ Payments: { __typename?: "PaymentsConnection" | undefined; } & { edges: ({ __typename?: "PaymentsEdge" | undefined; } & { node?: ({ __typename?: "Payment" | undefined; } & Pick<Payment, "id" | ... 20 more ... | "createdAt"> & { ...; }) | null | undefined; })[]; }; }'.
```

The second error (on `return wrappedGQLHook`):

```
Type '(...args: Parameters<Hook>) => { _data: T | undefined; client: ApolloClient<any>; data: GetPaymentsQuery | undefined; error?: ApolloError | undefined; ... 9 more ...; fetchMore: (<K extends "personId">(fetchMoreOptions: FetchMoreQueryOptions<...> & FetchMoreOptions<...>) => Promise<...>) & (<TData2, TVariables2, K e...' is not assignable to type '(...args: Parameters<Hook>) => ReturnType<Hook> & { _data: T | undefined; }'.
  Type '{ _data: T | undefined; client: ApolloClient<any>; data: GetPaymentsQuery | undefined; error?: ApolloError | undefined; loading: boolean; ... 8 more ...; fetchMore: (<K extends "personId">(fetchMoreOptions: FetchMoreQueryOptions<...> & FetchMoreOptions<...>) => Promise<...>) & (<TData2, TVariables2, K extends keyof ...' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Hook> & { _data: T | undefined; }'.
    Type '{ _data: T | undefined; client: ApolloClient<any>; data: GetPaymentsQuery | undefined; error?: ApolloError | undefined; loading: boolean; ... 8 more ...; fetchMore: (<K extends "personId">(fetchMoreOptions: FetchMoreQueryOptions<...> & FetchMoreOptions<...>) => Promise<...>) & (<TData2, TVariables2, K extends keyof ...' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Hook> & { _data: T | undefined; }'.
      Type '{ _data: T | undefined; client: ApolloClient<any>; data: GetPaymentsQuery | undefined; error?: ApolloError | undefined; loading: boolean; ... 8 more ...; fetchMore: (<K extends "personId">(fetchMoreOptions: FetchMoreQueryOptions<...> & FetchMoreOptions<...>) => Promise<...>) & (<TData2, TVariables2, K extends keyof ...' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Hook>'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to work backwards based on the signatures of two particular hooks, let's try to make a more generalized function.  Typescript should be able to infer the specific types based on which hook you pass in as an argument.

Start by thinking about what we know and what we don't know.  The things that we don't know become the generics.

- A hook is a function which takes some arguments (`A`).  There can be any number of arguments of any type (`A extends any[]`).
- It returns some object (`R`) which might have a property called 'data' (`R extends { data?: any }`).
- A reducer is a function which takes the data returned by the hook (`R['data']`) and maps it to some new value (`M`).
- The modified hook takes the same arguments (`A`) and returns an object with all of the hook returned values (`R`) and an additional property '_data' whose value is returned from the reducer (`M`) or might be undefined (`R & { _data: M | undefined }`).

Put that all together and we get this:

```
export function wrapGQLHook<A extends any[], R extends { data?: any }, M>(
    queryHook: (...args: A) => R,
    reducer: (data: R['data']) => M,
) {
    return (...args: A): R & { _data: M | undefined } => {
        const queryResult = queryHook(...args)
        let _data: M | undefined = undefined
        if (queryResult.data) {
            _data = reducer(queryResult.data)
        }
        return { ...queryResult, _data }
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me, but I can't test it very thoroughly without knowing the hook signatures.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsAzgFXNAvFAcniVQ20gIG4BYAKDoBMIBjAGzgCdoAzAVxWbAAlgHsUUXuggBxCMGLI06AIq8IHEAApOAcwBcsBIrI4AlAYDeUBnGBxLhkkoNwUIANoBdKAF9fNelomNk4efkFRcUkZOQBBBgYudCkVNQ1tDh0ARgMUXkQAI3UAGihdACYDdGAOIRQdcygrGzsDACUWEQ4GAB5q2vrSvML1AD5-OjoIAA8wLuAoPgFhMSgAdw44MGllABkACRERAGse2KgZ4FQGdDK3L1K2i%20mrlBum61s4AH4XN19SgBZUaaOhQcFQACOaRAhxOBk0ADpkbp0AZYqYoLhxm1imCIVwGLxmOoES17FA2u4COSCJ5MdioIC8bRMRZ8eCuMBeBxxEiUZk0VAMe0oAAyD4AfXJBkBUAAPhI3hBuHUIAxfFjxuzaBC9VBmGJqlCYR10LxWAt8ND1LCjsd%20YjUaYOfrWHIoNKvrKFUqmKqUOqsX6VWqGK69UJuFBNDaNGaLcBEeS2RH9eCvXZg4TiepY6aIObLcmvi7denfGnOXIeeIrMjEXGQAnLaVM3BK%20XwT46D3AgB6ABUg7Bg6gAHVNmBIBrorJ5EZSKlbVAABb20ejyk13m3OdyBRL1QrgBunHQpTArEkZU95KgYA4IjABrEdjqdR0t92QmNIm4W6HmgHSGt06Cjv2UyzPMr4oMa%204Lk4GDHhok5bDOwYbFsOwHPaoJdhIUjzkByEwiyeqaCmWpNFWUBRjGACEVFcrWtGGnBCxWCRtx%20Pg5K0SxvKOMY6ABHqPgsqYQA)

Comment: Amazing, much easier. Thanks for your help Linda! (I've converted the `any`s to `unknown`s but otherwise this worked perfectly as-is)